# Flutter Hero Animation with TextField Error

Tags: flutter

I want to create a Search functionality in one of my screen. The concept is as following: I have a TextField that marks the search functionality. When I tap it, I don't want to type into the TextField, but navigate to another Screen with a TextField inside the AppBar, where the user is supposed to search. (Similar to the Facebook App on Android). But I want to do this with a Hero transition from one TextField to the other TextField.

Here is some Code:

```
class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          child: Hero(
            tag: "search_text_field",
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  size: 24,
                ),
                hintText: "Search",
              ),
              focusNode: AlwaysDisabledFocusNode(),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, SEARCH_ROUTE);
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        ...moreWidgets
      ],
    );
  }
}


class SearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: AppTheme.grey,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Hero(
          tag: "search_text_field",
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              hintText: "Search",
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note that `FirstScreen` is a Widget inside another Screen, that has a Scaffold Widget. So both Screens already have a Scaffold Widget.**

The Hero transition works. But during the transition, I get the following Error:

```
The following assertion was thrown building TextField(decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Search")), dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery, UnmanagedRestorationScope], state: _TextFieldState#6cb29):
No Material widget found.

TextField widgets require a Material widget ancestor.
In material design, most widgets are conceptually "printed" on a sheet of material. In Flutter's material library, that material is represented by the Material widget. It is the Material widget that renders ink splashes, for instance. Because of this, many material library widgets require that there be a Material widget in the tree above them.

To introduce a Material widget, you can either directly include one, or use a widget that contains Material itself, such as a Card, Dialog, Drawer, or Scaffold.

The specific widget that could not find a Material ancestor was: TextField
  decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Search"))
  dirty
  dependencies: [MediaQuery, UnmanagedRestorationScope]
  state: _TextFieldState#6cb29
The ancestors of this widget were: 
  : Theme
    ThemeData#56afb
  : MaterialApp
    state: _MaterialAppState#ef29b
  : MyApp
  : BlocProvider<AuthCubit>
  ...
The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  TextField file:///Users/user/StudioProjects/project/lib/search_screen.dart:22:18
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      debugCheckHasMaterial.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:27:7)
#1      debugCheckHasMaterial (package:flutter/src/material/debug.dart:48:4)
#2      _TextFieldState.build (package:flutter/src/material/text_field.dart:1116:12)
#3      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4691:27)
#4      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
...
```

I think I get what is wrong: During the Hero Transition, the TextField widget is not wrapped inside a Material Widget, which causes the error (but I am not sure about that).

So what can I do about that?

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your both `TextField` with `Material`.

Full code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
            child: Hero(
              tag: "search_text_field",
              child: Material(
                child: TextField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      size: 24,
                    ),
                    hintText: "Search",
                  ),
                  // focusNode: AlwaysDisabledFocusNode(),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => SearchScreen(),
                    ));
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          // ...moreWidgets
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SearchScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.arrow_back,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        title: Hero(
          tag: "search_text_field",
          child: Material(
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Search",
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```